# Data structures: Why does %subst not working

Tags: rpgle

Have the following data structure:-

```
D Afthf071      E DS                  ExtName(thf071)                
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Data structure . . . . . . :  AFTHF071                            
 * External format  . . . . . :  TH071 : T0TU0TDDR/THF071            
 * Format text  . . . . . . . :  Customer Address Master File        
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------
D CSSTCN                         1S 0                                
D CSBRNN                        10S 0                                
D CSACTC                         1C
```

Have the following fields defined:-

```
D ABPOSTCODE      S            100c    
D accountCode     S              1c    
D w_cuno          S             10s 0
```

But when I do the following operation :-

```
 if %found(THf071a);                   
   clear ABPOSTCODE;                   
   ABPOSTCODE = %subst(AfThf071:1);    
   accountCode= %subst(AfThf071:12:1); 
 endif;   
 return;  
/end-free 

 Debug values:-
 EVAL AfThf071                    
 CSSTCN OF AFTHF071 = 0.          
 CSBRNN OF AFTHF071 = 0000000006. 
 CSACTC OF AFTHF071 = 1           

 EVAL AfThf071:x                                                      
  00000     F0F0F0F0 F0F0F0F0 F0F0F600 310030F0   - 00000000006....0
  00010     F0F0F0F0 F0F0F0F0 F0F3F9F0 F0F0F000   - 000000000390000.

EVAL accountCode:x  
 00000     0000...
```

was expecting `accountCode` value to be `x'0031`.

why is it `x'0000'` ?

**Note:** I'm using double byte.

Regards,
Jemrug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No conversion happens because `Afthf071` is not a `UCS2` value, it is a Char with length 13. If you were to try to pull out both bytes, and copy them to `accountCode`

```
accountCode = %subst(Afthf071: 12: 2);
```

You still get the same thing because the value in those bytes is `x'0031'` which is equivalent (and converted to) to `x'00000091'` in `UCS2` but only the first 'character' is copied to `accountCode`. So account code is still `x'0000'`.

So the takeaway is that just because you know you have some `UCS2` values embedded in an EBCDIC string, it doesn't mean that `%substr()` knows they are there. It treats the whole string as if it has the same `CCSID`.

Not real sure why you are trying to substring that thing anyway since you could just:

```
accountCode = csactc;
```

and everything would be correct.

Note when you convert `Afthf071` to all `UCS2` here:

```
ABPOSTCODE = %subst(AfThf071:1);
```

You will still have the same issue that `%subst()` doesn't know about the embedded `UCS2` characters, and you get:

```
00300030 00300030 00300030 00300030
00300030 00300000 00910020 00200020
00200020 00200020 00200020 00200020
... to the end of the field
```

Because it is treating that string as a `CHAR` with  the job CCSID. See that `x'00000091'` in there (on the second line), that is the Unicode equivalent of CCSID 37 `x'0031'`.

Unfortunately there is no way to cast a value to the appropriate CCSID other than to drop it into a data structure with an appropriate field type like this:

```
dcl-ds struct;
  ucs2field     Ucs2(1);
end-ds;
struct = %subst(AfThf071: 12: 1);
accountCode = ucs2Field;
```

But then it is just easier, since you already have the field `csactc` in a data structure to just use that. If your real problem is that you want `ABPOSTCODE` to be all `UCS2` including the `UCS2` bytes in the data structure, you are just going to have to substring it out like this:

```
ABPOSTCODE = %ucs2(%subst(AfThf071: 1: 11)) + CSACTC;
```

This will convert the portions that are not `UCS2` and leave the portions that are already `UCS2` alone. Now you have:

```
00300030 00300030 00300030 00300030
00300030 00300031 00200020 00200020
00200020 00200020 00200020 00200020
... to the end of the field
```

Comment: was the following : accountCode = %subst(Afthf071: 1: 2) a type o or should it havce been accountCode = %subst(Afthf071: 12: 2)

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.